# SwiftUI Picker not changing selection when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here is my list of objects:

```
let gameTypes = [
    GameType(id: "generalKnowledge", text: "❓ General Knowledge"),
    GameType(id: "geography", text: " Geography"),
    GameType(id: "music", text: " Music"),
    GameType(id: "sport", text: "⚽️ Sport"),
    GameType(id: "technology", text: " Technology"),
    GameType(id: "movies", text: " Movies & TV"),
]
```

And my `Picker` in my view:

```
@State var gameType: GameType = gameTypes[0]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            // Create game
            HStack {
                Picker("\(gameType.text)", selection: $gameType) {
                    ForEach(gameTypes, id: \.id){ type in
                        Text("\(type.text)").tag("\(type.id)")
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
```

My `Picker` successfully shows all `gameTypes` items in a list/menu when tapped. However when I tap an item in that list, `gameType` does not update.

Any idea why?

EDIT:

**GameType**

```
class GameType: Hashable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let text: String
    
    init(id: String, text: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
    }
    
    // Conform to Hashable
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    // Conform to Equatable (players will not be the same)
    static func == (lhs: GameType, rhs: GameType) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: what is GameType? Can you show code for it?

Comment: Sorry, added in edit @TusharSharma

Answer (score 1):

This is because the GameType and Tag types are different. And when selecting, swift does not work to assign an `Int` to the `GameType` type.
Just change your tag to the `type` instead of `type.id` and everything will work.
Example

```
HStack {
         Picker("\(gameType.text)", selection: $gameType) {
            ForEach(gameTypes, id: \.id) { type in
                 Text("\(type.text)").tag(type)
            }
         }
         .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a salvation, you need to use struc:

---

[image]

---

```
struct GameType: Hashable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    
    let id: String
    let text: String
    
    init(id: String, text: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: GameType, rhs: GameType) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}


let gameTypes = [
    GameType(id: "generalKnowledge", text: "❓ General Knowledge"),
    GameType(id: "geography", text: " Geography"),
    GameType(id: "music", text: " Music"),
    GameType(id: "sport", text: "⚽️ Sport"),
    GameType(id: "technology", text: " Technology"),
    GameType(id: "movies", text: " Movies & TV"),
]
```

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var gameTypeSelected: String = gameTypes[3].id
    
    var body: some View {

        Picker(selection: $gameTypeSelected, label: Text("")) {
  
            ForEach(gameTypes, id: \.id) { item in
                
                Text(item.text).id(item.id)
            }

        }
        
        Text("You selected: " + gameTypeSelected).bold()
        
    }
}
```